# Ivy loading unnecessary dependencies?

Tags: java, ant, build, ivy

I'm migrating a maven project to ant + ivy (it's an arbitrary decision, and it has to be done ).

The thing is that comparing both **WAR** files, the ant and the maven one, the former has a lot more 3rd party jars than the first one...

At first I thought that they were transitive dependencies but when I run `mvn dependency:tree`   they don't appear there.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

Just for the record, I'm aware of the `scope` attribute of maven. I'm excluding all the *provided* and *test* dependencies in the ivy.xml file

Comment: Could you give concrete examples? That could make finding the problem easier. Does ivy understand optional dependencies?

Comment: Sure. It's loading to the `lib` folder, deps like these: `asm`, `geronimo`, `antlr`, `ldapsdk`, etc. I have no relation to those in my code, not even close

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ivy:report Ant task to generate a report of the dependencies resolved by Ivy. In this report, you can see where the extra dependencies are comming from.

Maarten